# Why does Slack return a Segmentation fault after Fedora 29 upgrade?

Tags: linux, fedora, slack, fedora-29

I have upgraded Fedora from 28 to the latest 29 and Slack doesn't work anymore. It returns a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Edit: The issue has been fixed on Slack 3.3.4

Comment: Same problem is affecting other electron apps: https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/issues/78

Comment: Downgrading to Slack 3.1.1 could be a temporary solution - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/skype-not-opening-on-fedora-rawhide/c14eb9d2-563d-4697-b77d-077db7d77ffa

Comment: Same issue on ubuntu 18.10, I was able to successfully run slack after installing using snap `sudo snap install slack --classic`

Comment: For anyone running into this, the answer is Slack has built a custom rpm located here:  https://slack-files.com/T12KS1G65-FE65TFDD3-4f8a6c545f
I contacted support and this is what they sent.

Comment: Fixed in Slack for Linux 3.3.4: https://slack.com/release-notes/linux

Answer (score 78, accepted):

With `valgrind` I obtained this output:

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
 Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0xDBF060
   at 0xDBF060: ??? (in /usr/lib/slack/slack)
   by 0x7112071: node::http2::Http2Session::Callbacks::Callbacks(bool) (in /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so)
   by 0x7112134: ??? (in /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so)
   by 0x5853CE9: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
   by 0x5853DE9: _dl_init (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
   by 0x5845149: ??? (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.28.so)
```

It seems the issue is inside an "outdated" version of `libnode.so`. I just copied another version of `libnode.so` from the latest `atom.rpm` installation with:

`sudo mv /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so.old
sudo ln -s /usr/share/atom/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so`

---

**Edit**

Like user [Pierre Bellan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10586460/lundgren) already said, you can easily find other version of `libnode.so` on your OS with:
`sudo updatedb && locate libnode`

I used the atom one because I was sure about a recent working update of the editor.

Comment: If some one already has VSCode istead of Atom, I'm using VSCode library with success `sudo ln -fs /usr/share/code/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so`

Comment: I am getting a `/usr/lib/slack/slack: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/slack/slack: undefined symbol: udata_setCommonData_59` after doing this… Am I missing something else?

Comment: I get `undefined symbol: udata_setCommonData_59` as well. I ended up installing slack through flatpak. Just run `flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/com.slack.Slack.flatpakref`

Comment: with atom's node.so, I managed to start Slack. But I can't start a phone call, nothing happens except a black screen.

Comment: @DamienCassou have you tried with the Skype one instead of Atom?

Comment: Call will NOT work with neither of this libs (vscode, atom, skypeforlinux)

Comment: For Slack users who replaced libnode.so from somewhere else (and got the app running again) but still get the occasional crash, disable your notification sound for now. It seems if Slack tries to play the notification sound for a new message, it simply restarts instead of ever getting around to playing the clip.

Comment: @hypnomaki I managed to make calls working by also copying libffmpeg.so (from Skype).

Comment: I have received an answer from slack that they are working on it and they will ship it with 3.3.4 which will be released in near future

Comment: @DamienCassou thx I will try that out in the meanwhile

Comment: I used the libnode.so that came with gitkraken since I regularly update that (and I get a new version from them about once every 2 weeks)

Comment: I installed slack with flatpack and then used libnode.so from the flatpack version to fix my slack

Comment: This problem also affects debian/buster and slack 3.3.3. After moving libnode.so to different one problem is temporary fixed for me. I got libnode from skypeforlinux md5sum 40054393544b8258384876ce82955319

Comment: I haven't installed atom and no need it. I used libnode.so from skypeforlinux package. It also works. I think, it doesn't matter which libnode.so is used - just from one of new packages.

Answer (score 28):

As @Flat noted, the included libnode.so doesn't work with fedora 29.

Download the latest atom.rpm from http://atom.io (I'd never heard of it before...)

Install it, move the bad lib out of the way and symlink the new one in place:

```
sudo dnf install ~/Downloads/atom.x86_64.rpm
sudo mv /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so.bad
sudo ln -s /usr/share/atom/libnode.so /usr/lib/slack/libnode.so
```

There may be a better, or official source of libnode.so; but I looking quickly, I did not see one, and it wasn't installed anywhere else on my system.

Comment: I found that I already had another copy of libnode from skypeforlinux, and that version appears to work for Slack (copied /usr/share/skypeforlinux/libnode.so over to /usr/share/slack)

Comment: @lundgren is there a reason you suggest downloading atom manually instead of installing it from dnf? Manual installs should be avoided in favour of packages, so that the system is kept up-to-date and security issues can be closed.

Comment: Worked a treat!

Comment: For Slack users who replaced libnode.so from somewhere else (and got the app running again) but still get the occasional crash, disable your notification sound for now. It seems if Slack tries to play the notification sound for a new message, it simply restarts instead of ever getting around to playing the clip.

Comment: Slack refreshes everytime, if someone includes your @userid in a conversation .... and slack takes a few seconds to refresh every time. Not recommended.

Answer (score 14):

Thx @Flat for initial question and answer ;), i really need slack on app instead of web based version

Before installing something you don't need, check on directory if the lib is not already present from another sofware.

For example, i found a working libnode.so version on vscode too

```
sudo updatedb && locate libnode
```

Comment: please don't put question on answer section. Either use comment section or ask new question.

Comment: Have you tried Slack's Snap package?

Answer (score 14):

This issue was first reported on Arch linux when it was updated to glibc 2.28.  Both Fedora 29 and Ubuntu 18.10 users have hit this bug with many of the Electron apps. Slack's Snap package works fine on these versions of the distros. Users who can downgrade their glibc version to 2.27 do not seg fault.

[Issue reported on Electron apps](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13972)

On Nov 7th a new comment was added to the Electron issue - FYI on switching out libnode.  And if you do, you might want to switch it back when Slack releases the fix.

> For Slack users who replaced libnode.so from somewhere else (and got the app running again) but still get the occasional crash, disable your notification sound for now.
>   It seems if Slack tries to play the notification sound for a new message, it simply restarts instead of ever getting around to playing the clip.